# TLS connection with freeradius and openssl

Tags: openssl, wifi, tls1.2, freeradius, aaacertificateservices

In first, sorry for my english, I'm a baguette man.

I would like to make an EAP-TLS connection for wifi. I use freeradius for the authentification and Openssl for create certificates. So first I "create" a root-ca.key, then a root-ca.req and the a root-ca.crt. Then i do the same for the user certificate and sign the user's certificate with the root-ca. Then i change my freeradius with the correct certificates name in /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enable/eap and I install root-ca and and the user certificate on my phone. But, when i run freeradius in debug mode, it say  "eap_tls: ERROR: TLS Alert read:fatal:unknown CA".

My conf

/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enable/eap

```
##
##  eap.conf -- Configuration for EAP types (PEAP, TTLS, etc.)
##
##  $Id: a89a783663588017b12bcc076362e728261ba8f2 $

#######################################################################
#
#  Whatever you do, do NOT set 'Auth-Type := EAP'.  The server
#  is smart enough to figure this out on its own.  The most
#  common side effect of setting 'Auth-Type := EAP' is that the
#  users then cannot use ANY other authentication method.
#
eap {
    #  Invoke the default supported EAP type when
    #  EAP-Identity response is received.
    #
    #  The incoming EAP messages DO NOT specify which EAP
    #  type they will be using, so it MUST be set here.
    #
    #  For now, only one default EAP type may be used at a time.
    #
    #  If the EAP-Type attribute is set by another module,
    #  then that EAP type takes precedence over the
    #  default type configured here.
    #
    default_eap_type = tls

    #  A list is maintained to correlate EAP-Response
    #  packets with EAP-Request packets.  After a
    #  configurable length of time, entries in the list
    #  expire, and are deleted.
    #
    timer_expire = 60

    #  There are many EAP types, but the server has support
    #  for only a limited subset.  If the server receives
    #  a request for an EAP type it does not support, then
    #  it normally rejects the request.  By setting this
    #  configuration to "yes", you can tell the server to
    #  instead keep processing the request.  Another module
    #  MUST then be configured to proxy the request to
    #  another RADIUS server which supports that EAP type.
    #
    #  If another module is NOT configured to handle the
    #  request, then the request will still end up being
    #  rejected.
    #
    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no

    # Cisco AP1230B firmware 12.2(13)JA1 has a bug.  When given
    # a User-Name attribute in an Access-Accept, it copies one
    # more byte than it should.
    #
    # We can work around it by configurably adding an extra
    # zero byte.
    #
    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no

    #  Help prevent DoS attacks by limiting the number of
    #  sessions that the server is tracking.  For simplicity,
    #  this is taken from the "max_requests" directive in
    #  radiusd.conf.
    #
    max_sessions = ${max_requests}


    ############################################################
    #
    #  Supported EAP-types
    #


    #  EAP-MD5
    #
    #  We do NOT recommend using EAP-MD5 authentication
    #  for wireless connections.  It is insecure, and does
    #  not provide for dynamic WEP keys.
    #
    #md5 {
    #}


    #  EAP-pwd -- secure password-based authentication
    #
    #pwd {
    #   group = 19

    #   server_id = theserver@example.com

        #  This has the same meaning as for TLS.
        #
    #   fragment_size = 1020

        # The virtual server which determines the
        # "known good" password for the user.
        # Note that unlike TLS, only the "authorize"
        # section is processed.  EAP-PWD requests can be
        # distinguished by having a User-Name, but
        # no User-Password, CHAP-Password, EAP-Message, etc.
        #
    #   virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    #}


    #  Cisco LEAP
    #
    #  We do not recommend using LEAP in new deployments.  See:
    #  http://www.securiteam.com/tools/5TP012ACKE.html
    #
    #  Cisco LEAP uses the MS-CHAP algorithm (but not
    #  the MS-CHAP attributes) to perform it's authentication.
    #
    #  As a result, LEAP *requires* access to the plain-text
    #  User-Password, or the NT-Password attributes.
    #  'System' authentication is impossible with LEAP.
    #
    #leap {
    #}


    #  EAP-GTC -- Generic Token Card
    #
    #  Currently, this is only permitted inside of EAP-TTLS,
    #  or EAP-PEAP.  The module "challenges" the user with
    #  text, and the response from the user is taken to be
    #  the User-Password.
    #
    #  Proxying the tunneled EAP-GTC session is a bad idea,
    #  the users password will go over the wire in plain-text,
    #  for anyone to see.
    #
    #gtc {
        #  The default challenge, which many clients
        #  ignore..
        #
    #   challenge = "Password: "

        #  The plain-text response which comes back
        #  is put into a User-Password attribute,
        #  and passed to another module for
        #  authentication.  This allows the EAP-GTC
        #  response to be checked against plain-text,
        #  or crypt'd passwords.
        #
        #  If you say "Local" instead of "PAP", then
        #  the module will look for a User-Password
        #  configured for the request, and do the
        #  authentication itself.
        #
        #auth_type = PAP
    #}


    #  Common TLS configuration for TLS-based EAP types
    #  ------------------------------------------------
    #
    #  See raddb/certs/README for additional comments
    #  on certificates.
    #
    #  If OpenSSL was not found at the time the server was
    #  built, the "tls", "ttls", and "peap" sections will
    #  be ignored.
    #
    #  If you do not currently have certificates signed by
    #  a trusted CA you may use the 'snakeoil' certificates.
    #  Included with the server in raddb/certs.
    #
    #  If these certificates have not been auto-generated:
    #    cd raddb/certs
    #    make
    #
    #  These test certificates SHOULD NOT be used in a normal
    #  deployment.  They are created only to make it easier
    #  to install the server, and to perform some simple
    #  tests with EAP-TLS, TTLS, or PEAP.
    #
    #  Note that you should NOT use a globally known CA here!
    #  e.g. using a Verisign cert as a "known CA" means that
    #  ANYONE who has a certificate signed by them can
    #  authenticate via EAP-TLS!  This is likely not what you want.
    #
    tls-config tls-common {
        private_key_password = 1234
        private_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        #  If Private key & Certificate are located in
        #  the same file, then private_key_file &
        #  certificate_file must contain the same file
        #  name.
        #
        #  If ca_file (below) is not used, then the
        #  certificate_file below SHOULD also include all of
        #  the intermediate CA certificates used to sign the
        #  server certificate, but NOT the root CA.
        #
        #  Including the ROOT CA certificate is not useful and
        #  merely inflates the exchanged data volume during
        #  the TLS negotiation.
        #
        #  This file should contain the server certificate,
        #  followed by intermediate certificates, in order.
        #  i.e. If we have a server certificate signed by CA1,
        #  which is signed by CA2, which is signed by a root
        #  CA, then the "certificate_file" should contain
        #  server.pem, followed by CA1.pem, followed by
        #  CA2.pem.
        #
        #  When using "ca_file" or "ca_dir", the
        #  "certificate_file" should contain only
        #  "server.pem".  And then you may (or may not) need
        #  to set "auto_chain", depending on your version of
        #  OpenSSL.
        #
        #  In short, SSL / TLS certificates are complex.
        #  There are many versions of software, each of which
        #  behave slightly differently.  It is impossible to
        #  give advice which will work everywhere.  Instead,
        #  we give general guidelines.
        #
        certificate_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

        #  Trusted Root CA list
        #
        #  This file can contain multiple CA certificates.
        #  ALL of the CA's in this list will be trusted to
        #  issue client certificates for authentication.
        #
        #  In general, you should use self-signed
        #  certificates for 802.1x (EAP) authentication.
        #  In that case, this CA file should contain
        #  *one* CA certificate.
        #
        ca_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

        #  OpenSSL will automatically create certificate chains,
        #  unless we tell it to not do that.  The problem is that
        #  it sometimes gets the chains right from a certificate
        #  signature view, but wrong from the clients view.
        #
        #  When setting "auto_chain = no", the server certificate
        #  file MUST include the full certificate chain.
        #
    #   auto_chain = yes

        #  If OpenSSL supports TLS-PSK, then we can use a
        #  fixed PSK identity and (hex) password.  As of
        #  3.0.18, these can be used at the same time as the
        #  certificate configuration, but only for TLS 1.0
        #  through 1.2.
        #
        #  If PSK and certificates are configured at the same
        #  time for TLS 1.3, then the server will warn you,
        #  and will disable TLS 1.3, as it will not work.
        #
        #  The work around is to have two modules (or for
        #  RadSec, two listen sections).  One will have PSK
        #  configured, and the other will have certificates
        #  configured.
        #
    #   psk_identity = "test"
    #   psk_hexphrase = "036363823"

        #  Dynamic queries for the PSK.  If TLS-PSK is used,
        #  and psk_query is set, then you MUST NOT use
        #  psk_identity or psk_hexphrase.
        #
        #  Instead, use a dynamic expansion similar to the one
        #  below.  It keys off of TLS-PSK-Identity.  It should
        #  return a of string no more than 512 hex characters.
        #  That string will be converted to binary, and will
        #  be used as the dynamic PSK hexphrase.
        #
        #  Note that this query is just an example.  You will
        #  need to customize it for your installation.
        #
    #   psk_query = "%{sql:select hex(key) from psk_keys where keyid = '%{TLS-PSK-Identity}'}"

        #  For DH cipher suites to work, you have to
        #  run OpenSSL to create the DH file first:
        #
        #    openssl dhparam -out certs/dh 2048
        #
        dh_file = ${certdir}/dh

        #  If your system doesn't have /dev/urandom,
        #  you will need to create this file, and
        #  periodically change its contents.
        #
        #  For security reasons, FreeRADIUS doesn't
        #  write to files in its configuration
        #  directory.
        #
    #   random_file = /dev/urandom

        #  This can never exceed the size of a RADIUS
        #  packet (4096 bytes), and is preferably half
        #  that, to accommodate other attributes in
        #  RADIUS packet.  On most APs the MAX packet
        #  length is configured between 1500 - 1600
        #  In these cases, fragment size should be
        #  1024 or less.
        #
    #   fragment_size = 1024

        #  include_length is a flag which is
        #  by default set to yes If set to
        #  yes, Total Length of the message is
        #  included in EVERY packet we send.
        #  If set to no, Total Length of the
        #  message is included ONLY in the
        #  First packet of a fragment series.
        #
    #   include_length = yes


        #  Check the Certificate Revocation List
        #
        #  1) Copy CA certificates and CRLs to same directory.
        #  2) Execute 'c_rehash <CA certs&CRLs Directory>'.
        #     'c_rehash' is OpenSSL's command.
        #  3) uncomment the lines below.
        #  5) Restart radiusd
    #   check_crl = yes

        # Check if intermediate CAs have been revoked.
    #   check_all_crl = yes

        ca_path = ${cadir}

        # Accept an expired Certificate Revocation List
        #
    #   allow_expired_crl = no

        #  If check_cert_issuer is set, the value will
        #  be checked against the DN of the issuer in
        #  the client certificate.  If the values do not
        #  match, the certificate verification will fail,
        #  rejecting the user.
        #
        #  This check can be done more generally by checking
        #  the value of the TLS-Client-Cert-Issuer attribute.
        #  This check can be done via any mechanism you
        #  choose.
        #
    #   check_cert_issuer = "/C=GB/ST=Berkshire/L=Newbury/O=My Company Ltd"

        #  If check_cert_cn is set, the value will
        #  be xlat'ed and checked against the CN
        #  in the client certificate.  If the values
        #  do not match, the certificate verification
        #  will fail rejecting the user.
        #
        #  This check is done only if the previous
        #  "check_cert_issuer" is not set, or if
        #  the check succeeds.
        #
        #  In 2.1.10 and later, this check can be done
        #  more generally by checking the value of the
        #  TLS-Client-Cert-Common-Name attribute.  This check
        #  can be done via any mechanism you choose.
        #
    #   check_cert_cn = %{User-Name}

        #  Set this option to specify the allowed
        #  TLS cipher suites.  The format is listed
        #  in "man 1 ciphers".
        #
        #  For EAP-FAST, use "ALL:!EXPORT:!eNULL:!SSLv2"
        #
        cipher_list = "DEFAULT"

        #  If enabled, OpenSSL will use server cipher list
        #  (possibly defined by cipher_list option above)
        #  for choosing right cipher suite rather than
        #  using client-specified list which is OpenSSl default
        #  behavior.  Setting this to "yes" means that OpenSSL
        #  will choose the servers ciphers, even if they do not
        #  best match what the client sends.
        #
        #  TLS negotiation is usually good, but can be imperfect.
        #  This setting allows administrators to "fine tune" it
        #  if necessary.
        #
        cipher_server_preference = no

        #  You can selectively disable TLS versions for
        #  compatability with old client devices.
        #
        #  If your system has OpenSSL 1.1.0 or greater, do NOT
        #  use these.  Instead, set tls_min_version and
        #  tls_max_version.
        #
    #   disable_tlsv1_2 = no
        disable_tlsv1_1 = yes
        disable_tlsv1 = yes

        #  Set min / max TLS version.  Mainly for Debian
        #  "trusty", which disables older versions of TLS, and
        #  requires the application to manually enable them.
        #
        #  If you are running Debian trusty, you should set
        #  these options, otherwise older clients will not be
        #  able to connect.
        #
        #  Allowed values are "1.0", "1.1", "1.2", and "1.3".
        #
        #  Note that the server WILL NOT permit negotiation of
        #  TLS 1.3.  The EAP-TLS standards for TLS 1.3 are NOT
        #  finished.  It is therefore impossible for the server
        #  to negotiate EAP-TLS correctly with TLS 1.3.
        #
        #  The values must be in quotes.
        #
        tls_min_version = "1.2"
        tls_max_version = "1.2"

        #  Elliptical cryptography configuration
        #
        #  Only for OpenSSL >= 0.9.8.f
        #
        ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"

        #  Session resumption / fast reauthentication
        #  cache.
        #
        #  The cache contains the following information:
        #
        #   session Id - unique identifier, managed by SSL
        #   User-Name  - from the Access-Accept
        #   Stripped-User-Name - from the Access-Request
        #   Cached-Session-Policy - from the Access-Accept
        #
        #  See also the "store" subsection below for
        #  additional attributes which can be cached.
        #
        #  The "Cached-Session-Policy" is the name of a
        #  policy which should be applied to the cached
        #  session.  This policy can be used to assign
        #  VLANs, IP addresses, etc.  It serves as a useful
        #  way to re-apply the policy from the original
        #  Access-Accept to the subsequent Access-Accept
        #  for the cached session.
        #
        #  On session resumption, these attributes are
        #  copied from the cache, and placed into the
        #  reply list.
        #
        #  You probably also want "use_tunneled_reply = yes"
        #  when using fast session resumption.
        #
        #  You can check if a session has been resumed by
        #  looking for the existence of the EAP-Session-Resumed
        #  attribute.  Note that this attribute will *only*
        #  exist in the "post-auth" section.
        #
        #  CAVEATS: The cache is stored and reloaded BEFORE
        #  the "post-auth" section is run.  This limitation
        #  makes caching more difficult than it should be.  In
        #  practice, it means that the first authentication
        #  session must set the reply attributes before the
        #  post-auth section is run.
        #
        #  When the session is resumed, the attributes are
        #  restored and placed into the session-state list.
        #
        cache {
            #  Enable it.  The default is "no". Deleting the entire "cache"
            #  subsection also disables caching.
            #
            #  As of version 3.0.14, the session cache requires the use
            #  of the "name" and "persist_dir" configuration items, below.
            #
            #  The internal OpenSSL session cache has been permanently
            #  disabled.
            #
            #  You can disallow resumption for a particular user by adding the
            #  following attribute to the control item list:
            #
            #    Allow-Session-Resumption = No
            #
            #  If "enable = no" below, you CANNOT enable resumption for just one
            #  user by setting the above attribute to "yes".
            #
            enable = no

            #  Lifetime of the cached entries, in hours. The sessions will be
            #  deleted/invalidated after this time.
            #
            lifetime = 24 # hours

            #  Internal "name" of the session cache. Used to
            #  distinguish which TLS context sessions belong to.
            #
            #  The server will generate a random value if unset.
            #  This will change across server restart so you MUST
            #  set the "name" if you want to persist sessions (see
            #  below).
            #
        #   name = "EAP module"

            #  Simple directory-based storage of sessions.
            #  Two files per session will be written, the SSL
            #  state and the cached VPs. This will persist session
            #  across server restarts.
            #
            #  The default directory is ${logdir}, for historical
            #  reasons.  You should ${db_dir} instead.  And check
            #  the value of db_dir in the main radiusd.conf file.
            #  It should not point to ${raddb}
            #
            #  The server will need write perms, and the directory
            #  should be secured from anyone else. You might want
            #  a script to remove old files from here periodically:
            #
            #    find ${logdir}/tlscache -mtime +2 -exec rm -f {} \;
            #
            #  This feature REQUIRES "name" option be set above.
            #
        #   persist_dir = "${logdir}/tlscache"

            #
            #  As of 3.0.20, it is possible to partially
            #  control which attributes exist in the
            #  session cache.  This subsection lists
            #  attributes which are taken from the reply,
            #  and saved to the on-disk cache.  When the
            #  session is resumed, these attributes are
            #  added to the "session-state" list.  The
            #  default configuration will then take care
            #  of copying them to the reply.
            #
            store {
                Tunnel-Private-Group-Id
            }
        }

        #  As of version 2.1.10, client certificates can be
        #  validated via an external command.  This allows
        #  dynamic CRLs or OCSP to be used.
        #
        #  This configuration is commented out in the
        #  default configuration.  Uncomment it, and configure
        #  the correct paths below to enable it.
        #
        #  If OCSP checking is enabled, and the OCSP checks fail,
        #  the verify section is not run.
        #
        #  If OCSP checking is disabled, the verify section is
        #  run on successful certificate validation.
        #
        verify {
            #  If the OCSP checks succeed, the verify section
            #  is run to allow additional checks.
            #
            #  If you want to skip verify on OCSP success,
            #  uncomment this configuration item, and set it
            #  to "yes".
            #
        #   skip_if_ocsp_ok = no

            #  A temporary directory where the client
            #  certificates are stored.  This directory
            #  MUST be owned by the UID of the server,
            #  and MUST not be accessible by any other
            #  users.  When the server starts, it will do
            #  "chmod go-rwx" on the directory, for
            #  security reasons.  The directory MUST
            #  exist when the server starts.
            #
            #  You should also delete all of the files
            #  in the directory when the server starts.
            #
        #   tmpdir = /tmp/radiusd

            #  The command used to verify the client cert.
            #  We recommend using the OpenSSL command-line
            #  tool.
            #
            #  The ${..ca_path} text is a reference to
            #  the ca_path variable defined above.
            #
            #  The %{TLS-Client-Cert-Filename} is the name
            #  of the temporary file containing the cert
            #  in PEM format.  This file is automatically
            #  deleted by the server when the command
            #  returns.
            #
        #   client = "/path/to/openssl verify -CApath ${..ca_path} %{TLS-Client-Cert-Filename}"
        }

        #  OCSP Configuration
        #
        #  Certificates can be verified against an OCSP
        #  Responder. This makes it possible to immediately
        #  revoke certificates without the distribution of
        #  new Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs).
        #
        ocsp {
            #  Enable it.  The default is "no".
            #  Deleting the entire "ocsp" subsection
            #  also disables ocsp checking
            #
            enable = no

            #  The OCSP Responder URL can be automatically
            #  extracted from the certificate in question.
            #  To override the OCSP Responder URL set
            #  "override_cert_url = yes".
            #
            override_cert_url = yes

            #  If the OCSP Responder address is not extracted from
            #  the certificate, the URL can be defined here.
            #
            url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"

            # If the OCSP Responder can not cope with nonce
            # in the request, then it can be disabled here.
            #
            # For security reasons, disabling this option
            # is not recommended as nonce protects against
            # replay attacks.
            #
            # Note that Microsoft AD Certificate Services OCSP
            # Responder does not enable nonce by default. It is
            # more secure to enable nonce on the responder than
            # to disable it in the query here.
            # See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770413%28WS.10%29.aspx
            #
        #   use_nonce = yes

            # Number of seconds before giving up waiting
            # for OCSP response. 0 uses system default.
            #
        #   timeout = 0

            # Normally an error in querying the OCSP
            # responder (no response from server, server did
            # not understand the request, etc) will result in
            # a validation failure.
            #
            # To treat these errors as 'soft' failures and
            # still accept the certificate, enable this
            # option.
            #
            # Warning: this may enable clients with revoked
            # certificates to connect if the OCSP responder
            # is not available. Use with caution.
            #
        #   softfail = no
        }
    }


    #  EAP-TLS
    #
    #  As of Version 3.0, the TLS configuration for TLS-based
    #  EAP types is above in the "tls-config" section.
    #
    tls {
        #  Point to the common TLS configuration
        #
        tls = tls-common

        #  As part of checking a client certificate, the EAP-TLS
        #  sets some attributes such as TLS-Client-Cert-Common-Name. This
        #  virtual server has access to these attributes, and can
        #  be used to accept or reject the request.
        #
    #   virtual_server = check-eap-tls
    }


    #  EAP-TTLS -- Tunneled TLS
    #
    #  The TTLS module implements the EAP-TTLS protocol,
    #  which can be described as EAP inside of Diameter,
    #  inside of TLS, inside of EAP, inside of RADIUS...
    #
    #  Surprisingly, it works quite well.
    #
    #ttls {
        #  Which tls-config section the TLS negotiation parameters
        #  are in - see EAP-TLS above for an explanation.
        #
        #  In the case that an old configuration from FreeRADIUS
        #  v2.x is being used, all the options of the tls-config
        #  section may also appear instead in the 'tls' section
        #  above. If that is done, the tls= option here (and in
        #  tls above) MUST be commented out.
        #
        #tls = tls-common

        #  The tunneled EAP session needs a default EAP type
        #  which is separate from the one for the non-tunneled
        #  EAP module.  Inside of the TTLS tunnel, we recommend
        #  using EAP-MD5.  If the request does not contain an
        #  EAP conversation, then this configuration entry is
        #  ignored.
        #
        #default_eap_type = md5

        #  The tunneled authentication request does not usually
        #  contain useful attributes like 'Calling-Station-Id',
        #  etc.  These attributes are outside of the tunnel,
        #  and normally unavailable to the tunneled
        #  authentication request.
        #
        #  By setting this configuration entry to 'yes',
        #  any attribute which is NOT in the tunneled
        #  authentication request, but which IS available
        #  outside of the tunnel, is copied to the tunneled
        #  request.
        #
        #  allowed values: {no, yes}
        #
        #copy_request_to_tunnel = yes

        #  As of version 3.0.5, this configuration item
        #  is deprecated.  Instead, you should use
        #
        #    update outer.session-state {
        #      ...
        #    }
        #
        #  This will cache attributes for the final Access-Accept.
        #
        #  The reply attributes sent to the NAS are usually
        #  based on the name of the user 'outside' of the
        #  tunnel (usually 'anonymous').  If you want to send
        #  the reply attributes based on the user name inside
        #  of the tunnel, then set this configuration entry to
        #  'yes', and the reply to the NAS will be taken from
        #  the reply to the tunneled request.
        #
        #  allowed values: {no, yes}
        #
        #use_tunneled_reply = yes

        #  The inner tunneled request can be sent
        #  through a virtual server constructed
        #  specifically for this purpose.
        #
        #  A virtual server MUST be specified.
        #
        #virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"

        #  This has the same meaning, and overwrites, the
        #  same field in the "tls" configuration, above.
        #  The default value here is "yes".
        #
    #   include_length = yes

        #  Unlike EAP-TLS, EAP-TTLS does not require a client
        #  certificate. However, you can require one by setting the
        #  following option. You can also override this option by
        #  setting
        #
        #    EAP-TLS-Require-Client-Cert = Yes
        #
        #  in the control items for a request.
        #
        #  Note that the majority of supplicants do not support using a
        #  client certificate with EAP-TTLS, so this option is unlikely
        #  to be usable for most people.
        #
    #   require_client_cert = yes
    #}


    #  EAP-PEAP
    #

    ##################################################
    #
    #  !!!!! WARNINGS for Windows compatibility  !!!!!
    #
    ##################################################
    #
    #  If you see the server send an Access-Challenge,
    #  and the client never sends another Access-Request,
    #  then
    #
    #       STOP!
    #
    #  The server certificate has to have special OID's
    #  in it, or else the Microsoft clients will silently
    #  fail.  See the "scripts/xpextensions" file for
    #  details, and the following page:
    #
    #   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/814394/
    #
    #  If is still doesn't work, and you're using Samba,
    #  you may be encountering a Samba bug.  See:
    #
    #   https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6563
    #
    #  Note that we do not necessarily agree with their
    #  explanation... but the fix does appear to work.
    #
    ##################################################

    #  The tunneled EAP session needs a default EAP type
    #  which is separate from the one for the non-tunneled
    #  EAP module.  Inside of the TLS/PEAP tunnel, we
    #  recommend using EAP-MS-CHAPv2.
    #
    #peap {
        #  Which tls-config section the TLS negotiation parameters
        #  are in - see EAP-TLS above for an explanation.
        #
        #  In the case that an old configuration from FreeRADIUS
        #  v2.x is being used, all the options of the tls-config
        #  section may also appear instead in the 'tls' section
        #  above. If that is done, the tls= option here (and in
        #  tls above) MUST be commented out.
        #
        #tls = tls-common

        #  The tunneled EAP session needs a default
        #  EAP type which is separate from the one for
        #  the non-tunneled EAP module.  Inside of the
        #  PEAP tunnel, we recommend using MS-CHAPv2,
        #  as that is the default type supported by
        #  Windows clients.
        #
        #default_eap_type = mschapv2

        #  The PEAP module also has these configuration
        #  items, which are the same as for TTLS.
        #
        #copy_request_to_tunnel = yes

        #  As of version 3.0.5, this configuration item
        #  is deprecated.  Instead, you should use
        #
        #    update outer.session-state {
        #      ...
        #    }
        #
        #  This will cache attributes for the final Access-Accept.
        #
        #use_tunneled_reply = yes
```

In this conf, i use the default openssl's certificates. But it's the same problem when i make my own certificates. I tried every tuto on internet but nothing.

If you need more informations, i will give it to you !

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

hope you solved it, but just for the lonely admin walking by, I assume your problem lies within the following line:

```
auto_chain = yes
```

Change it to

```
auto_chain = no
```

Otherwise, your freeradius server will try to chain the certificate, referred to under `ca_file` to the certificates present in the operating system.